# Smack library integration in Android : Showing exception

Tags: android, smack

I want to create a chat application on Android.For that I am using XMPP,for these I am using Smack API.I am trying an source code given [here.](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)

But when I tried to run the app it is showing an exception "*Failed to connect to gtalk.google.com*".

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
```

Anyone can tell what I should do to solve this issue.

Comment: please post the exception stack trace ? have you given proper internet permissions in android manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved, instead of **gtalk.google.com** I've used **talk.google.com**.